# Verify Game Integrity through Steam API?

Tags: steam, verify, steam-web-api, integrity

Is it possible to verify a game through Steam with the API? This would be very helpful for a script I'm writing.

Comment: The WebAPI? You want to verify a game's integrity like the client does?

Comment: Yes. I need to automate the process so the user doesn't have to do so before running.

Comment: I don't believe that to be possible, sorry.

Comment: DAMN! Well, there goes my plan... Thanks anyway.